# aws_acm_certificate seems to have changed its state output possibly due to a provider update- am I doing this wrong?

Tags: amazon-web-services, validation, terraform, amazon-route53, aws-acm-certificate

```
Terraform v0.12.12
+ provider.aws v3.0.0
+ provider.template v2.1.2
```

Before I was doing this:

```
resource "aws_route53_record" "derps" {
  name    = aws_acm_certificate.mycert[0].resource_record_name
  type    = aws_acm_certificate.mycert[0].resource_record_type
  zone_id = var.my_zone_id
  records = aws_acm_certificate.mycert[0].resource_record_value
  ttl     = 60
}
```

And that worked fine for me about a week ago.

I just did a plan and got an error:

```
records = [aws_acm_certificate.mycert.domain_validation_options[0].resource_record_value]

This value does not have any indices.
```

Now I don't pin provider versions, so I'm assuming I pulled a newer version and the resource changed.

After fighting with this and realizing it's not a list (even though when doing `show state` it sure looked like one) I am now doing this to make it a list:

```
resource "aws_route53_record" "derps" {
  name    = sort(aws_acm_certificate.mycert.domain_validation_options[*].resource_record_name)[0]
  type    = sort(aws_acm_certificate.mycert.domain_validation_options[*].resource_record_type)[0]
  zone_id = var.my_zone_id
  records = [sort(aws_acm_certificate.mycert.domain_validation_options[*].resource_record_value)[0]]
  ttl     = 60
}
```

This resulted in no changes which is good. But if I use the example for doing this from the docs they now use for_each: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/acm_certificate_validation

```
resource "aws_route53_record" "example" {
  for_each = {
    for dvo in aws_acm_certificate.example.domain_validation_options : dvo.domain_name => {
      name    = dvo.resource_record_name
      record  = dvo.resource_record_value
      type    = dvo.resource_record_type
      zone_id = dvo.domain_name == "example.org" ? data.aws_route53_zone.example_org.zone_id : data.aws_route53_zone.example_com.zone_id
    }
  }

  allow_overwrite = true
  name            = each.value.name
  records         = [each.value.record]
  ttl             = 60
  type            = each.value.type
  zone_id         = each.value.zone_id
}

resource "aws_acm_certificate_validation" "example" {
  certificate_arn         = aws_acm_certificate.example.arn
  validation_record_fqdns = [for record in aws_route53_record.example : record.fqdn]
}
```

Is the above the correct way to do this now? Am I going to run into issues doing it the way I currently am? Doing it like above would result in a destroy/recreate (i guess I could import it myself but that's painful).

Is doing it my way not going to result in unexpected diffs?

### Edit

So, more specific for my issue. This is what I see when I look at the state:

```
terraform state show aws_acm_certificate.mycert

    ...
    domain_name               = "*.mydom.com"
    domain_validation_options = [
        {
            domain_name           = "*.mydom.com"
            resource_record_name  = "_11111111111.mydom.com."
            resource_record_type  = "CNAME"
            resource_record_value = "_1111111111.11111111.acm-validations.aws."
        },
        {
            domain_name           = "mydom.com"
            resource_record_name  = "_11111111111.mydom.com."
            resource_record_type  = "CNAME"
            resource_record_value = "_1111111111.111111111.acm-validations.aws."
        },
    ]
    ...
```

By using sort I'm effectively using count which of course results in a destroy/recreate if the order changes. But in my case I think that's unlikely?? I also don't fully understand the difference between just using the values from the wildcard validation config and using both of them.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The AWS Terraform provider was recently upgraded to version 3.0. This version comes with [a list of breaking changes](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/releases/tag/v3.0.0). I recommend consulting the [AWS provider 3.0 upgrade guide](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/guides/version-3-upgrade#resource-aws_acm_certificate).

The issue you are encountering is because the `domain_validation_options` attribute is now a set instead of a list. From that guide:

> Since the `domain_validation_options` attribute changed from a list to a set and sets cannot be indexed in Terraform, the recommendation is to update the configuration to use the more stable resource `for_each` support instead of `count`

I recommend using the new `foreach` syntax, as the upgrade guide recommends, in order to avoid unexpected diffs. The guide states that you will need to use `terraform state mv` to move the old configuration state to the new configuration, in order to prevent the resources from being recreated.

Comment: I updated my question with more specific info about my route53/acm issue to confirm in this case its hopefully not too tenuous

Comment: foreach is not a good solution. In my environment, different domain name in different aws account. we can not use foreach, we have to add dns separately in each aws account's route53, we need to specify different provider to different route53's resource, just tolist(aws_acm_certificate.cert.domain_validation_options)[0].resource_record_name works for me.

Answer (score 11):

This is the same problem we were facing just now.. we use for_each to define hosting for multiple sites according to provided local variables, now, since we already use for_each we can't use it for workaround of their changes.. unfortunate.

I didn't want to go with sort so I checked what Jimmy wrote but it didn't work for this case due to output being index, I fixed it by using [0] instead of [*]:

```
resource "aws_route53_record" "cert_validation" {
  for_each = local.web_pages
  allow_overwrite = true
  name            = tolist(aws_acm_certificate.cert[each.key].domain_validation_options)[0].resource_record_name
  type            = tolist(aws_acm_certificate.cert[each.key].domain_validation_options)[0].resource_record_type
  records         = [tolist(aws_acm_certificate.cert[each.key].domain_validation_options)[0].resource_record_value]
  zone_id         = var.aws_hosted_zone
  ttl             = 60
}
```

works for us now ;)

Answer (score 4):

These 3 sets of code below work. (I used `Terraform v0.15.0`)

*The difference between `1st` and `2nd` is `[0]` and `.0`

1st:

```
resource "aws_route53_record" "myRecord" {
  zone_id = aws_route53_zone.myZone.zone_id
  name    = tolist(aws_acm_certificate.myCert.domain_validation_options)[0].resource_record_name
  type    = tolist(aws_acm_certificate.myCert.domain_validation_options)[0].resource_record_type
  records = [tolist(aws_acm_certificate.myCert.domain_validation_options)[0].resource_record_value]
  ttl = "60"
  allow_overwrite = true
}
```

2nd:

```
resource "aws_route53_record" "myRecord" {
  zone_id = aws_route53_zone.myZone.zone_id
  name    = tolist(aws_acm_certificate.myCert.domain_validation_options).0.resource_record_name
  type    = tolist(aws_acm_certificate.myCert.domain_validation_options).0.resource_record_type
  records = [tolist(aws_acm_certificate.myCert.domain_validation_options).0.resource_record_value]
  ttl = "60"
  allow_overwrite = true
}
```

3rd:

```
resource "aws_route53_record" "myRecord" {
  for_each = {
    for dvo in aws_acm_certificate.myCert.domain_validation_options : dvo.domain_name => {
      name   = dvo.resource_record_name
      record = dvo.resource_record_value
      type   = dvo.resource_record_type
    }
  }

  name            = each.value.name
  records         = [each.value.record]
  ttl             = 60
  type            = each.value.type
  zone_id         = aws_route53_zone.myZone.zone_id
  allow_overwrite = true
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also cheat with `tolist`.

e.g. rewrite `aws_acm_certificate.mycert.domain_validation_options[*].resource_record_name` as `tolist(aws_acm_certificate.mycert.domain_validation_options)[*].resource_record_name`

I had to do this in a module, as this particular module resource already had a `count` in it, and I knew I'd only ever have one entry.